# How to view hidden files in Nautilus in Debian 9

Tags: debian

I'm getting up and running with Debian 9, but can't find a way to view hidden files (files that begin with a period) in folders via the default Debian file manager. With Ubuntu it was as simple as checking a box in the Nautilus preferences, but I can't find that option in Debian 9:

[image: Debian 9 Nautilus preferences]

Note: Please don't answer that I should use `ls -a`, i want to be able to quickly see hidden files in the GUI. Also, I'd prefer not to completely change my file manager to, say, KDE. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click (ctr+h) on keyboard.